# vuex state resets to value that is not default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

on successful action, i save the time of token expiration as follows:

```
 sessionStorage.setItem('expires_at', new Date().getTime() + JSON.parse(response.data.expires_in))
```

I also have the following attribute in my state:

```
 isAuthenticated: new Date().getTime() < JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('expires_in'))
```

isAuthenticated is true at first, however it resets to false on page refresh eventhough the fllowing value is true

```
new Date().getTime() < JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('expires_in'))
```

Comment: It's hard to realize the problem with just two lines of code. 
You need to show the whole component.

Comment: I just found the problem, I had to multiply the token expiration date by 1000 
     sessionStorage.setItem('expires_at', new Date().getTime() + JSON.parse(response.data.expires_in) *1000)